# Sent Usdt to a usdc wallet. Can it be retrieved?

Tags: help

I unfortunately sent Usdt to a usdc wallet.
Can it be retrieved?

Comment: Can you show us the transaction signature ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exactly where you sent it.

If the usdc address is an associated-token-account, the recipient should be able to recover it using `RecoverNested` on the associated token account program: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/177a6c94d751e49be0e299b0155823195a21e7fe/token/js/src/instructions/associatedTokenAccount.ts#L92

This instruction allows you to recover funds that were sent to an associated-token-account which is owned by another associated-token-account. You can read more about it at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/177a6c94d751e49be0e299b0155823195a21e7fe/associated-token-account/program/src/instruction.rs#L37

Comment: Maybe we should consolidate all similar questions into https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/how-can-i-use-instructionrecover-nested

Answer (score 0):

the crypto transactions are designed to be permanent but you can try contacting  the person who owns the wallet you sent the funds to, but If the wallet is on an exchange, contact their support immediately. Some exchanges might assist, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).