# I sent my token (from Trust Wallet) to my ATA (Solflare), the balance still 0? Can I recover from this?

Tags: spl-token, ata

So basically what I did was, sending my Solana token from my Trust Wallet to my ATA of the token on my Solflare. The balance still says 0, how do I recover from this? Is it possible or not?

And for my future dumb**, the correct way is to just send it to my Solana address just like other network?

Comment: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/how-can-i-use-instructionrecover-nested

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question. Indeed you just send to the wallet and it will create the token account for your "wallet account."

I'm researching if you can withdraw from a token account created within a token account. It seems like you may be able to, but I'm not confident.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).